# How to let GCC for MIPS restore the stack pointer just before returning?

Tags: gcc, mips

When GCC for MIPS compiles a leaf function, it generates assembly code like the following:

```
   addiu $sp, $sp, 72
   sb    $v1, 0($v0)
   lbu   $a0, 5($t2)
   lw    $v0, 0($t1)
   sb    $a0,1($v0)
   lbu   $v1,6($t2)
   lw    $v0,0($t1)
   sb    $v1,2($v0)
   lw    $a0,0($t1)
   lbu   $v0,7($t2)
   jr    $ra
   sb    $v0,3($a0)
```

where  "addiu  $sp, $sp, 72" is the instruction that
pops the stack pointer,  there're many instructions between this instruction and the return
instruction "jr      $ra".

This could cause problem in a pre-emptive OS: when the current thread is interrupted just between the "addiu $sp, $sp, 72" instruction and "jr $ra" by an hardware interrupt, after the interrupt service routine finishes, a thread of higher priority will be scheduled to run,  it will ruin the original thread's stack.

This only happens when the function is a leaf function,  does GCC for MIPS have any compiling options not to generate code like above?

Comment: The function is done with the stack after the `addiu`, so this won't hurt.

Comment: Restoring the stack pointer just before `jr $ra` would only make the problematic window smaller, rather than eliminating it. Fortunately, what you're describing is not a real problem here.

Comment: FYI, pre-emptive threads each get their own stack, no thread runs on the stack of another.  (User-mode signal handlers, however, may run to completion on the stack of a suspended thread, depending on OS.)

Comment: Yes, it depends on OS.  Maybe this is an OS problem(an old VxWorks). OS should take care of this risk.